# jQuery automatically fill inputs in the table

Tags: jquery

I have the following table. How can I make so that if one of the columns filled out and I click on the icon next to the name of the column - other columns are filled in automatically with the same values.

For example if fields of first column have following values:
Name - John
Email - johnson@gmail.com
Phone - 123456
Country - USA

Other columns of table will be filled in by the same values. Or if second of for example fourth column has some value - on click filled in other columns with the same values.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wy22s/241/)

```
     <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>First <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></th>
                    <th>Second <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></th>
                    <th>Thired <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></th>
                    <th>Fourth <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Name</td>
                    <td><input id="first-name" class="form-control"></input></td>
                    <td><input id="second-name" class="form-control"></input></td>
                    <td><input id="third-name" class="form-control"></input></td>
                    <td><input id="fourth-name" class="form-control"></input></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Email</td>
                    <td><input id="first-email" class="form-control"></input></td>
                    <td><input id="second-email" class="form-control"></input></td>
                    <td><input id="third-email" class="form-control"></input></td>
                    <td><input id="fourth-email" class="form-control"></input></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Phone</td>
                    <td><input id="first-phone" class="form-control"></input></td>
                    <td><input id="second-phone" class="form-control"></input></td>
                    <td><input id="third-phone" class="form-control"></input></td>
                    <td><input id="fourth-phone" class="form-control"></input></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Country</td>
                    <td>
                        <select id="first-country" class="form-control">
                            <option>ITALY</option>
                            <option>FRANCE</option>
                            <option>UKRAINE</option>
                            <option>USA</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select id="second-country" class="form-control">
                            <option>ITALY</option>
                            <option>FRANCE</option>
                            <option>UKRAINE</option>
                            <option>USA</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select id="third-country" class="form-control">
                            <option>ITALY</option>
                            <option>FRANCE</option>
                            <option>UKRAINE</option>
                            <option>USA</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select id="fourth-country" class="form-control">
                            <option>ITALY</option>
                            <option>FRANCE</option>
                            <option>UKRAINE</option>
                            <option>USA</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
$("th i ").click(function () {
  var index = $(this).parent().index();
  $("tr").each(function () {
    $(this).find("input").val($(this).find("td:eq(" + index + ") input").val());
    $(this).find("select").val($(this).find("td:eq(" + index + ") select").val())
  })
})
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/Wy22s/245/)

Slightly improved version:

```
$("th i ").click(function () {
  var index = $(this).parent().index();
  $("tr").each(function () {
    var val;
    if ($(this).find("input").length) {
        val = $(this).find("td:eq(" + index + ") input").val();
        $(this).find("input").val(val);
    } else {
        val = $(this).find("td:eq(" + index + ") select").val()
        $(this).find("select").val(val);
    }
  })
})
```